# qt socket -> java(android)

Tags: java, qt, sockets

I am trying to develop a client-server application.
The server is Qt and Java client (android)
I can receive data from the client.
But when I send data to the client, receive it but not in the right format.

Code C++

```
QByteArray paquet;
QDataStream out(&paquet, QIODevice::WriteOnly);
out << message; // On ajoute le message      
out << "\n";

// Envoi du paquet préparé à tous les clients connectés au serveur
for (int i = 0; i < clients.size(); i++)
{
     clients[i]->write(paquet);
}
```

Code Java

```
in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

while(mRun) {
       Log.e(TAG, "En attente de message");
       mServerMessage = in.readLine();

 if(mServerMessage != null && mMessageListener != null){
    Log.e("REPONSE FROM SERVER", "S: Received Message: " + mServerMessage);
    mMessageListener.messageReceived(mServerMessage);
        }
}
```

out

```
?N?E?W?C?L?I?E?N?T?
```

Comment: you need to set the character encoding to UTF-16.`new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream(),"UTF-16");`

Comment: QDataStream encodes data in binary and adds its own control characters. Java's streams won't be able to decode that properly. readline() also doesn't make sense on binary data. If all you want is text, just convert directly to e.g. utf8: `paquet = message.toUtf8() + '\n'`

Comment: 'paquet=message.toUtf8() + '\n'' is good. Thanks for all

Answer (score 0):

```
paquet = message.toUtf8() + '\n';
```